# How to pass parameter to sort's compare function?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, stl

I want to sort a vector v using this

```
std::sort(v.begin(),v.end(),cmpr);
```

where my cmpr function is

```
bool cmpr(int a,int b, int c) 
{
     return a%c <= b%c;
}
```

now i want to know how can i pass c?

Comment: you're looking for `std::bind`

Comment: As mentioned you can use [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), or create a [*functor* object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/what-are-c-functors-and-their-uses) with `c` as a member that's initialized on construction. You could also use a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: Even if you got your code to work, your comparison function does not follow a `strict-weak-ordering`, as you're returning `true` or `false` for equal values of `a` and `b`.  So you need to fix that also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) to wrap your comparator. A full example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

auto make_cmpr(int c)
{
    return [c](int a, int b) {
        return a%c <= b%c;
    };
}

int main()
{
    int a[5] = {2, 4, 1, 3, 5};
    std::sort(a, a + 5, make_cmpr(3));

    /* or directly
    int c = 3;
    std::sort(a, a + 5, 
        [c](int a, int b) {
            return a%c <= b%c;
        }
    );
    */

    for (int e : a) std::cout << e << ' ';
}
```